# Summation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+ix)(n+iy)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to compute the following sum for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$: 
$$
S(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+ix)(n+iy)}
$$

What is interesting is that we have following sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+ix)(n+iy)} = \frac{\pi}{x-y} \left[ \coth(\pi x) - \coth(\pi y) \right]$, so I was initially thinking that my sum $S$ would look similar.

Using this identity, we have:
$$
\frac{\pi}{x-y} \left[ \coth(\pi x) - \coth(\pi y) \right] = 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{(n+ix)(n+iy)} \ + \ \frac{1}{xy} \ + \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+ix)(n+iy)} \\
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(-n+ix)(-n+iy)} \ + \ \frac{1}{xy} \ + \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+ix)(n+iy)} \\
= S(-x,-y)+ \frac{1}{xy} + S(x,y)
$$

I thought I'd be able to use this, but I'm getting stuck. I'd like to not use polygammas, but understand that maybe I can't avoid this. Any ideas on how to attack this?

Comment: $$ \forall\,a\neq b,\text{Re}(a),\text{Re}(b)>0,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}$$ where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)$. You cannot avoid the digamma function.

Comment: thanks very much. I have come to the same conclusion since last night. It looks like my sum goes to $S(x,y) = \frac{1}{xy} + \frac{\psi(ix) - \psi(iy)}{ix-iy}$.